# in VC++2008 Form Application which component is used for display many lines text?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am writing a **socket client** **Form Application**. i want to display message we sent and received in an area to **monitor the communication**. is the **ListBox** a right component for this purpose?

**EDIT:**

Why the ListBox display is not line by line but only showing at the end? the TextBox is showing new text each time.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                this->listBox1->MultiColumn = true;

                for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
                {
                    this->textBox1->AppendText(String::Format( "Item {0}", i ));
                    this->listBox1->BeginUpdate();                  
                    this->listBox1->Items->Add( String::Format( "Item {0}", i ));
                    listBox1->EndUpdate();
                    Sleep(500);
                }               
             }
```

I was thinking use **label** but cannot find a **scrolling** control with it.

This is the first time I use Form Application. Please be patient.

Comment: Please say something useful to show this is a stupid question and then downvotes. if the question is too hard for you, then you should upvote it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use a TextBox control, set it to multiline and prepend, rather than append the new lines.  This way the most recent text is always on top and you don't have to worry about scrolling.  You can do the same with a label control, too, but you lose the ability to scroll down.

If course, depending on how long-running this is, you may need to clean up instead of just keeping all the text indefinitely.  You'll run into memory issues if you do keep all of the text indefinitely.

Comment: finally i found the TextBox can have scrollbar and can be set to bigger size. I cannot drag it larger but from the property window i can change its size. it's too hard when i don't know how to do it but it's so easy when i found the way.

Comment: I need to find out how to do cleanup by just remove older text but keep recent ones.